# Слово "рапорт", почему  у не моряков ударение на первом слоге?

Tags: этимология

Хотелось бы узнать, причем тут порт в качестве корня.
У фасмера невменяемая рекурсивная ссылка репорт-рапорт.
А ведь значения разные. А вот почему?

Comment: Ударение в слове *рапорт* моряки ставят на втором слоге : рапОрт.  
Рапорт и репортаж Вам кажутся далекими по значению?

Comment: Ошибся, поправил.Эти два слова близки по корню и в корне отличаются по значению, поскольку в английском report re-отрицание, пеРЕадресация. 
В слове паспорт, свершение действия,по-французски pas- прошел порт. ра в слове рапорт - это что?

Comment: Ra = re, см. этимологию OED :  
>**rapport** (n.) 
1660s, "reference, relation, relationship," from French rapport "bearing, yield, produce; harmony, agreement, intercourse," back-formation from rapporter "bring back; refer to," from re- "again" (see re-) + apporter "to bring," from Latin apportare "to bring," from ad- "to" (see ad-) + portare "to carry" (see port (n.1)).

Comment: Не RA на RE, а RAP на RE, что в корне поменяло смысл. Во французском это тоже явная приставка, причем  и слово report имеется и производные от него,но набор значений невелик, по сравнению  со словом rapport, В английском тоже есть rapport но это не калька с французского. Там корень rap-легкий удар,стук.
Понять можно, это когда корабль в порту швартуется, или в дверь стучат.
А основное значение - связь. синоним реляции. Корабль привез новости и товар-продукцию,  что и отражено в английской этимологии-термины используются в торговле.

Comment: В французском нет явного  толкования RAP, судя по другим словам это синоним выбора. Непонятно как это к порту относится во всех приведенных  в словарях значениях. Получается - это Французы поимели  кальку, а потом ее расширили.
Потеря двойного согласного в других языках понятна, так как смысла приставки не перенеслось. Вот и вопрос, что она означает буквально.
Английская этимология неудовлетворительна, поскольку в французском приставка Аp  и так имеется: Аpport и др.

Comment: Читайте текст внимательнее, не торопитесь. Rapport = re-apport, from re- + apporter ... from Latin apportare, ad- + portare.

Comment: это натянуто, а точнее притянуто за уши, поскольку в этимологии отсутствует понятия места, в обоих языках, это не ворота. это именно порт в понятии места стоянки и нахождения. торговая точка. а уже потом понятие нести откуда и куда.
Это логика экономики, а не дурной лингвистики.Потому и паспорт, портмоне, значение отчетности и связи, и множество значений во всех языках, в том числе и в русском-порты.портки. Это история, так же не притянутая за уши. Да и нет такого слова apportare в старых латинских словарях, новодел этот итальянский. есть -ap-porto, значение нести.

Comment: есть ap-porto, основное значение принести. А остальные значения  и так прилагаются, потому как от причины и  следствие.
В общем это..., если не торопиться, в воротах латинских надо утопиться и торговать в портике без портков.  Шучу.

Comment: Apportare - одна из форм apporto :  
>apporto
ap–porto, āvī, ātum, āre
1) приносить (magnas divitias domum Pl); привозить, доставлять (frumentum ex Sicilia C);
2) наносить, причинять (damnum Ter); вызывать (morbos Lcr);
3) сообщать (nuntium Ter; insolitam rem auribus Lcr): adventum a. Pt = advenire.   
  
http://linguaeterna.com/vocabula/show.php?n=3683  
Porto и portus сами в словаре латинском найдете.

Comment: нет возможности комментировать, переношу в ответ.Дерзкий Grantum,
А может вы скажете,какую смысловую нагрузку несут эти окончания  AVI, ATUM, ARE? тогда и обсудим.

Comment: Основные глагольные формы.  
>1) praesens indicativi activi personae primae singularis, который почти у всех глаголов заканчивается на о и отвечает на вопрос «что я делаю?». 

>2) perfectum indicativi activi personae primae singularis, который заканчивается на i и отвечает на вопрос «что я сделал?». 

>3) супин, отглагольное существительное со значением цели при глаголах движения, который заканчивается на um и переводится сочетанием «чтобы + инфинитив». 

>4) инфинитив, который у правильных глаголов заканчивается на re и соответствует русскому инфинитиву (что делать, что сделать).

Comment: Ну а теперь, все просто - и противоречие на лицо,  сначала вы толковали одно, теперь по правилам играть, так по правилам  смысл не поменялся.   Спряжение.   
Это вам временное отличие, а не смысловое. Принес, приносил, принесу,  может быть, я вас поцелую, потом, (at um-от ум) за это.  
Ре, если вспомню за что. Ре-пу(по) целую.  
Finita.  
Я это к чему, тянуто это все и в латыни. AVI, ATUM, ARE, и такое ARIUS. Однозначно, слишком много проколов смысловых и временных, история в словах противоречит официальной.

Comment: И не говорите.

Comment: Чем вам Фасмер-то не понравился?!
Нет там никакой рекурсивной ссылки.
Все корректно. Можно спорить, но не таким образом, честно.
"re", кстати, - ни разу не отрицание.

Answer (score 2):

Потому, что моряки заимствовали слово из голландского, куда оно попало из французского.
Во французском ударение на втором слоге.
Аналогичное ситуация со словом компАс и некоторыми другими.

В обычном "сухопутном" языке слова компас и рапорт изначально тоже несли французское ударение, но, обрусев, поменяли его. Это не редкость. Сравните, например, "пасспОрт", ставший обычным паспортом.

Answer (score 1):

Рorter (фр.)  - нести, rapporter - приносить обратно. Рапорт - это как бы ОТВЕТ на запрос о состоянии дел, отсюда значение ОБРАТНОЙ связи.

Обратная связь отражена в слове "раппорт" того же происхождения:

1) повторяющаяся часть (мотив) рисунка (узора) на ткани, трикотаже, вышивке, обоях и пр.;

2) термин в психологии, имеющий несколько смежных значений; подразумевает установление специфического контакта, включающего определенную меру доверия или взаимопонимания с человеком или группой людей.

Comment: Оно похоже, но базируется на предположении, что рапорт происходит от "раппорт" и сохраняет смысловую с ним связь. А это не доказано. Я никакого "запроса" и тем более обратной связи в слове "рапорт" не наблюдаю. 
В этом смысле возведение к английскому "report" - в одном из значений "находится в подчинении" даже более оправдано. "Рапорт" подается вышестоящему. И как правило - без какого либо запроса, просто по ситуации. В этом вся штука.

Comment: У Черных rapporter (фр.) - СНОВА приносить, доставлять, позже - докладывать. У Шанского - rapport (донесение) от rapporter - приносить ОБРАТНО, доносить, от рorter - нести.